# Please check the parameter 'sonar.host.url'

Tags: maven-2, hudson, sonarqube

I want to enable hudson+sonar so I did with following steps:

1.Installed sonar 3.4.1 and started sonar server .Now I can access `http://localhost:9000` on browser.

2.In configuration on hudson I have provided sonar installation details but only database details are provided over there like database login,password ,url etc.

2.Created new job in hudson ,used the git repository where currently my project is ,and in post build actions I have selected sonar.

But I am going to build the job it fetch the contents from git repositoty correctly, but I am getting following exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project Engile: Sonar server can not be reached at http://localhost:9000. Please check the parameter 'sonar.host.url'. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project Engile: Sonar server can not be reached at http://localhost:9000. Please check the parameter 'sonar.host.url'.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Sonar server can not be reached at http://localhost:9000. Please check the parameter 'sonar.host.url'.
```

I have not added anything in settings.xml file.I have no clue abount this issue,can Anybody give me some solution...

**1.Hudson configuration:**

[image]

**2.Hudson job configuration:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the Hudson/Jenkins plugin to set a specific URL for your Sonar server. Please have a look at this part of the documentation: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Configuring+Sonar+Jenkins+Plugin#ConfiguringSonarJenkinsPlugin-AddingSonarServer

You can see that there is a "Server URL" field, that you must fill.

Comment: yes but I am using default i.e http://localhost:9000 its not http://myserver:9000 so what could be the problem.

Comment: How do you trigger Sonar? Are you sure that you're using the Sonar post build action?

Comment: In hudson configuration I have provided sonar installation details and in hudson job post build action I have selected sonar option and jdk home specified over there. any extra parameters are needed?

Comment: Read the documentation and check again step by step that you've done everything. If is still does not work, you should attach screenshots of your Hudson config page and your Hudson post build action config section so that it's easier to see what's the problem.

Comment: I have attached screenshots plz have a look. And according to above documentation if we are not using sonar runner then is it neccessary that it needs any changes in settings.xml file fron ~/m2/setting.xml

Comment: I don't understand: you said in the description that you can access Sonar at http://myserver:9000, but you configured "http://localhost:9000" (which is passed to the post build action as we can see in the log). Why don't you set "http://myserver:9000" on the "server URL" parameter??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23555/discussion-between-pallavi-and-fabrice-sonar-team)